# Seed function in Brownian motion

Tags: r

when I simulate Brownian Motion, I need to 10 to 20  seeds in R. my code is following, but I think this only a fixed seed , How to create under different seeds, thank you

```
u <- 0.05
sigma <- 0.2
t <- 1
steps <- 252
S0 <- 100
dt <- u / steps
set.seed(10:20)
epsilon_t_vec <- rnorm(steps)
epsilon_t_vec <- append(0, epsilon_t_vec)
dwt_vec <- epsilon_t_vec * sqrt(dt)
St_vec <- c()
St_vec[1] <- S0
for(i in 1:steps) {
  dwt <- dwt_vec[i+1]
  St_vec[i+1] <- St_vec[i] + u * St_vec[i] * dt + sigma * St_vec[i] * dwt
}
St_vec
```

Comment: If you want to run your code multiple times with different seeds, you probably need to create a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Where the seed is being changed in a second loop every time and the output is appended to a list with the length of your seeds.

```
u <- 0.05
sigma <- 0.2
t <- 1
steps <- 252
S0 <- 100
dt <- u / steps

seeds <- 10:20
St_vec <- list()


for(s in 1:length(seeds)) {
set.seed(seeds[s])

epsilon_t_vec <- rnorm(steps)
epsilon_t_vec <- append(0, epsilon_t_vec)

dwt_vec <- epsilon_t_vec * sqrt(dt)
St_vec[[s]] <- c(S0) 



for(i in 1:steps) {
  dwt <- dwt_vec[i+1]
  St_vec[[s]][i+1] <- St_vec[[s]][i] + u * St_vec[[s]][i] * dt + sigma * St_vec[[s]][i] * dwt
}
}
```

Comment: ， Can I ask you another question？I wrote this coding :AR <- function(b1,n=1000)
{
    seeds<-10
    x<-runif(n,-0.5,0.5)#white noise
    y<-10
    y[1] <- 10+x[1]
    y[2] < b1*y[1]+x[2]
    for(t in 2:n){
        y[t] <- b1*y[t-1]+x[t]
    }
    plot.ts(y,main=paste("y[t]=",b1,"*y[t-1]","+x[t]"))
    y
}
y<-AR(0.75)  this is use uniform to create random number, but my professor asks me to create normal distribution by Box_Muller. Can you give me some hints? thank you